# Failed to fetch updates : How to fix corrupt source file

Tags: release-loki, updates, settings, software-installation, appcenter

[image]

The error message contains:

**Failed to fetch updates**

This may have been caused by external, manually added software repositories or a corrupted sources file.

details:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

W: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Comment: please help me to fix this or if their is a way to clear or remove all problematic repositories without loosing my current state of things (personal files, settings ) i would be really greatful

Answer (score 1):

As yu can see in http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu/dists/ xenial is not supported. You have trusty or utopic version only.
But you can use anther repository for Tweaks:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```