# New install of Elementary OS - Failed to Fetch Updates

Tags: system-installation, updates

This may have been caused by external, manually added software repositories or a corrupted sources file.

I see this question has been asked a few times - I mean no disrespect - just wondering what the best answer is and if it is still the same.

My screen is exactly as shown here: 
[Failed to fetch updates : How to fix corrupt source file](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15660/failed-to-fetch-updates-how-to-fix-corrupt-source-file)

But it just seems weird to be adding some personal ppa to solve it. 
But then again maybe philip.scott is the right place?  Just want someone to tell me it is safe and the current solution.

Thanks so much
Frank

PS - here is the entire listing of my exact error pop up:

```
E: The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Comment: I had the same issue. I ran the command to automate the process and the issue is fixed. Thanks T0ba!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `hera` to `bionic` in the next files:

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list

Use the following command to automate process:

```
find /etc/apt -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 sed -i 's/hera/bionic/g'
```

Comment: Thanks T0ba! - That sounds like the answer.  I don't have access to the PC right now - we are in quarantine in place but when this is over I will give it a go.  Stay healthy and safe!

Comment: I saw the affected PC yesterday and T0ba's answer above worked just fine.  Sure makes sense.  I admit I didn't use his command answer because I like seeing exactly what is going on.  But I edited the 3 files he lists and changed 'hera' to 'bionic' and did a system update.  All good to go now.

OH - BTW - I don't have enough reputation to mark his answer as the solution...  So - if someone else wants to I'd appreciate it. 
Stay Healthy and Safe!

Comment: Done, I have reputation marked the solution.